# Can not call twice button click function in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am a basic in cocos2dx.
I am using "UIviewcontroller" as below

```
-(void)showLeaderBoar:(NSString*) category
{
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboad=[[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
   if(leaderboad!=nil)
   {
       UIWindow *window=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow];
       UIViewController * currentModalViewController=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
      [window addSubview:currentModalViewController.view];
      leaderboad.category=category;
       leaderboad.timeScope=GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
       leaderboad.leaderboardDelegate=self;
       [[LeaderBoardManager sharedManager] reportScore:10000 forCategory:category];

       [currentModalViewController presentModalViewController:leaderboad animated:YES];
    }
[leaderboad release];
}

-(void) leaderboardViewControllerDidFinish:(GKLeaderboardViewController *)viewController
{

  [viewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  
   [viewController release];

}
```

when I run and click Leaderboard button first time I can get,but next time I click i couldn't call this function.
Can anyone please point out my error? Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: which function is the click event function?

Comment: I am calling the first method(showLeaderBoar).Thanks.

Comment: Try comment this line "[viewController release];" in the second function.This may cause memory leak.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But it seems doesn't effect.

Comment: How did you bind the click function to your button?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Also, consider presenting it from different viewcontrollers.